# Java SWT table cells comparing

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface, swt

I'w working on GUI with SWT. The software get txt file and push all the data to table. Is it possible run over each cell in a row to compare cells? and run over each row in the table to do it.

I can't understand how if I have only `.getColumnCount()`

and another thing: is it possible to highlight different cells?

***EDIT:***

```
                        for (int loopIndexPM1ColumnTools = 0; loopIndexPM1ColumnTools < tableConfigurationSystemColumnLP.size(); loopIndexPM1ColumnTools++) {
                        TableColumn column = new TableColumn(tableConfigurationLP, SWT.NONE, loopIndexPM1ColumnTools);
                        column.setWidth(100);
                        column.setText(tableConfigurationSystemColumnLP.get(loopIndexPM1ColumnTools));
                      }

                    /*
                     * Loop for adding items to each column in CE-LP Tab
                     */
                      for (int loopIndexPM1ColumnTools = 0; loopIndexPM1ColumnTools < CE_LP_Parameter.size(); loopIndexPM1ColumnTools++) {
                        TableItem item = new TableItem(tableConfigurationLP, SWT.NONE);
                        item.setText(0, CE_LP_Parameter.get(loopIndexPM1ColumnTools));
                        item.setText(1, CE_LP1_Value.get(loopIndexPM1ColumnTools));
                        item.setText(2, CE_LP2_Value.get(loopIndexPM1ColumnTools));
                        item.setText(3, CE_LP3_Value.get(loopIndexPM1ColumnTools));

                      }

                      for (int loopIndexPM1ColumnTools = 0; loopIndexPM1ColumnTools < tableConfigurationSystemColumnLP.size(); loopIndexPM1ColumnTools++) {
                          tableConfigurationLP.getColumn(loopIndexPM1ColumnTools).pack();
                      }
```

***EDIT:***

```
                          int tbl_clm = tableConfigurationLP.getColumnCount();
                      int tbl_rows = tableConfigurationLP.getItemCount();
                      for(int i=0;i<tbl_clm;i++) {
                          for(int x=0;x<tbl_rows;x++) {
                              System.out.println(tableConfigurationLP.getColumn(i).getText());
                          }
                      }
```

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in a Question. Tables have lots of methods for accessing rows and columns. Show us how you are creating the table.

Comment: edited, please look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Table` has

- `getItemCount()` to give you the number of rows
- `getItem(rowIndex)` get the `TableItem` at row `rowIndex`
- `getItems()` get all the `TableItem`s
- `getColumnCount()` get the number of columns

`TableItem` has

- `getText(colIndex)` get the text of column `colIndex`

So for example:

```
Table table = .... the table

int rows = table.getItemCount();
int columns = table.getColumnCount();

for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rows; ++rowIndex) {
   TableItem rowItem = table.getItem(rowIndex);

   for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < columns; ++colIndex) {
       String colValue = rowItem.getText(colIndex);

       ....
   }
}
```

Comment: edited, why its printing only the first row couple of times?

Comment: You are calling `Table.getColumn(index)` which gives you the `TableColumn` header for a column **not** the column data. See example added to answer for getting all the columns.